Where does ss command gather its data for ports etc
When trying to see port clashes within my system, many websites online recommend using /etc/services or ss -tunl to see port info
I am noticing /etc/services is providing different information to -ss on most occasions.
Output comparison examples
sudo cat /etc/services

ftp                21/udp
ftp                21/sctp
ssh                22/tcp
ssh                22/udp
ssh                22/sctp
telnet             23/tcp
telnet             23/udp
smtp               25/tcp

versus
ss -tunl

Netid  State   Recv-Q   Send-Q   Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port                               
udp    UNCONN  0        0        0.0.0.0:5353          0.0.0.0:*                                  
udp    UNCONN  0        0        0.0.0.0:46670         0.0.0.0:*                                  
udp    UNCONN  0        0        [::]:5353             [::]:*                                  
udp    UNCONN  0        0        [::]:38838            [::]:*   

Is /etc/services a static data file and should only be used as a guide, not an true reflection of what the real port configuration of the system is.
Where does ss program gather this port data, and how can I modify/delete some of the ports, either through ss or another program?

/etc/services does nothing but offer a way to map port numbers to names of protocols typically used on that port. It has nothing to do with the services that actually run on your machine.

What does "modify some of the ports" mean? That makes no sense to me, could you please elaborate what this should do?

@MarcusMüller When using ss -tunl I can see a port I want to use already exists in the output(in this case 51820), When trying to use port 51820 in my wireguard config file in, I get an RTNETLINK error when using wg-quick up wg0 to bring up iface
Conversely, Using a different port in my wireguard config file works fine.
So I wondered how can I modify(IE remove) a port from the ss output, and resolve the issue behind port 51820

you don't need to modify the ss output, you need to figure out what is using that port (in your case, almost certainly another wireguard instance that is already running!) and stop that. I.e., the problem is not that you're shown that the port is already in use, the problem is that you want to do something twice on the same port, which can't logically work out.

@MarcusMüller There definitely isnt another wireguard instance running, cmd ip a returns only two interfaces, lo and eth0. When i load up wireguard, I will see three, wg0 being the 3rd
Also the OS is a fresh install, therefore limited variables at play

@MarcusMüller can you tell me where does ss gather its port information?

yes, directly from the network stack, via NETLINK. Does this really help you?

@MarcusMüller it might help me find out whats using port 51820, as we cant rely on your comment about it being wireguard, despite you being so certain. Aside from this, I posted this question to learn a deeper understanding, not solve a superficial problem and retire.

but why don't you simply ask "how to find out what is using a port", if that's what you want to learn? That's literally what ss is for! In your case, it can't tell you a program that is using that, because there is no program, you set up a wireguard interface in the kernel that is configured to listen on that port.

@MarcusMüller I kind of did ask that, And online received conflicting info, I did also phrase it as "where does ss gather port data"... Anyhow, it appeared that port 51820 is being used by avahi-daemon, whatever that is

I tried to find where you kind of asked that, but it seems to me you really didn't!

@MarcusMüller I really did - Check the opening post of my original question Where does ss program gather this port data

yes, you asked where ss got the data; you never asked about what you wanted to know, how to figure out what owns a listening port!

The file /etc/services only provides number to name mapping for ports, and has nothing to do with what ports ss lists.  Additionally, the names in this file are common uses for the ports, not what the port is actually used for on your system, as any program (with sufficent permissions) can open any port for any purpose.  Basically /etc/services is a subset of the IANA's assigned numbers registry.
What ss lists is what ports on your system are in use.  If it is listed in ss, it is in use.  If you run ss -p as root, it should list what process specifically has the port open.
You can't directly modify what ports are in use.  What you need to do is use sudo ss -p to find out what program is using the port and kill it.  Or, conversely, if a port is not listed in ss and you expect it to be, start the service that uses the port.
It is a common misguided perception that ports can be created and deleted.  Ports are just a number, they always exist and can't be deleted or created.  They are either in use or not in use.

Your answer was similar to Net64, both helped me. However as you pointed out to use ss with sudo, i selected yours, This helped me gain more info than I was able to without using sudo

thanks for the additional part about in use or not, it helps

Note also that a port is a 4-tuple (source ip, source port, target ip, target port) and that this can only be open by one process for TCP ports with a few rare exceptions.

These are two different things.  The /etc/services file shows you which port a service would normally use, similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers .
ss is a command to show you which services are currently active on your machine that wait for incoming connections, like a web server which would LISTEN on TCP ports 80 and 443. It will also show you currently open outgoing connections like those by a web browser or ssh client to a web/ssh server.
ss is similar to the older command netstat which has been deprecated in favour of ss.
